# How can I create an index show all fields using regex

Tags: regex, mongodb, indexing, pymongo, wildcard

I want to create an index in mongodb to show all fields where `value = xyz`

I am new to indexes. Is there a way to do that?

Can I do something like:

create index where `browser: /^Amazon /i`

Sorry, I know the question is ambiguous, But not really sure how to work with indexes yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create an index for a `browser` field, then yes, it will help you when you search for `browser: /^Amazon/` or similar. Please bear in mind, **the index is used only when the regex is started with `^` and contain some static text after it** (like in your example `/^Amazon/`).

Let assume your collection is called `myCollection` (please rename it to your own!) Then you can create index the following way:

```
db.myCollection.createIndex({ browser: 1 })
```

You can think about indexes as dictionaries. If I ask you to open some dictionary (I mean real paper book, language dictionary) and find there all words starting with "Amaz" (like `/^Amaz/`) then you can do it fast. Opposite, if I ask you to find all words ending with "Amaz" (`/Amaz$/`), or containing "Amaz" in the middle (`/Amaz/`) it will take long time for you, because you'll have to go through all words in the dictionary and check it. Mongo works similarly :)